# Creating multilevel nodes and appending to a given node on YouTube video page view

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add a small GUI to YouTube video page to add some features for youtube (from extension). The problem is that it just display the first node. All nodes inside the first node are not displayed. Here is the code:

```
function appendGUI(){
        toplevel = document.getElementById("top-level-buttons");
        ytbutton = document.createElement("ytd-button-renderer");
        ytbutton.setAttribute("class", "style-scope ytd-menu-renderer force-icon-button style-default size-default");
        ytbutton.setAttribute("button-renderer", "true");
        ytbutton.setAttribute("style-action-button", "");
        ytbutton.setAttribute("is-icon-button", "");
        ytbutton.setAttribute("use-keyboard-focused", "");
        ytbutton.setAttribute("id", "yt-looper-video");
        
        atag = document.createElement("a");
        atag.setAttribute("style", "padding-top:10px !important;");
        atag.setAttribute("class", "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-button-renderer");
        atag.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
        
        ytstring = document.createElement("yt-formatted-string");
        ytstring.setAttribute("id", "text");
        ytstring.setAttribute("class", "style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-default size-default");
        
        txtnode = document.createTextNode("Loop");
        
        /* ytbutton.innerHTML = `
            <a style="padding-top:10px !important;" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-button-renderer" tabindex="-1">
                <yt-formatted-string id="text" class="style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-default size-default">
                    Loop
                </yt-formatted-string>
            </a>`; */
        ytstring.appendChild(txtnode);
        atag.appendChild(ytstring);
        ytbutton.appendChild(atag);
        toplevel.appendChild(ytbutton);
    }
```

I even tried to use innerHTML, but still the same.
I just use the debugger of Chrome to run the above function, and call it, but just the node "ytd-button-render" was added, others NOT.

Note that there is a node with id "top-level-buttons" in every YouTube video page. It contains LIKE, DISLIKE, SHARE, SAVE...